# Cannot run wordcount example in flink

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea, apache-flink

After import pom of flink-release-1.4.2, I try to run wordcount example.But I cannot build it becauseof lots of errors about Scala.

```
 Information:19-2-20 上午2:45 - Compilation completed with 53 errors and 0 warnings in 2s 439ms
/media/maple/新加卷/download/Notes/flink-release-1.4.2/flink-examples/flink-examples-batch/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/examples/scala/clustering/KMeans.scala
Error:(81, 14) not found: type ExecutionEnvironment
    val env: ExecutionEnvironment = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
Error:(81, 37) not found: value ExecutionEnvironment
    val env: ExecutionEnvironment = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
Error:(85, 17) not found: type DataSet
    val points: DataSet[Point] = getPointDataSet(params, env)
Error:(131, 74) not found: type DataSet
  def getPointDataSet(params: ParameterTool, env: ExecutionEnvironment): DataSet[Point] = {
Error:(131, 51) not found: type ExecutionEnvironment
  def getPointDataSet(params: ParameterTool, env: ExecutionEnvironment): DataSet[Point] = {
Error:(86, 20) not found: type DataSet
    val centroids: DataSet[Centroid] = getCentroidDataSet(params, env)
```

So what's wrong. And when I only import pom of flink-examples, the wordcount program could run normally. For example:

[image: run normally]

I have tried reimport Maven, invalidate caches, and install Scala plugins.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please copy/paste the error messages here directly rather than posting a link to a screenshot.

Comment: Does it work from the command line Maven?

Comment: Please dont edit an answer into the question.. You can use the answer section and accept it

Answer (score 0):

With IntelliJ you'll need the JetBrains Scala plugin, and you'll need to open the project structure dialog and add a Scala SDK in the Global Libraries section.

Comment: Flink 1.4.2 is no longer supported. Do you see the same problems with a more recent version, such as 1.7.2?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved.I run `mvn clean package -DskipTests` and successfully rebuild.